# JS Search if in a div class is found another div with name "Name"

Tags: javascript

I have a couple of div classes with the same name for an example

```
<div class="Mydiv">
```

I want to search each individual div with a name "MyDiv" for a sub 
`<div class="Subdiv">` if there is do ...

Example of the code:

```
<div class="Mydiv">
</div>
<div class="Mydiv">
 <div class="Subdiv">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That may be a funny question, but I'm pretty sure I've seen your name in agar.io? Does tennisball ring a bell? =P

Comment: So basically you want to find every `.Subdiv` that are within `.Mydiv` elements?

Comment: Nope, I guess it was some imposture trying to steal my identity xD

Comment: I want to know if in `.Mydiv` there is `.Subdiv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go through each `.Mydiv`, and do something whenever you find a `.Subdiv` and something else if you don't find a `.Subdiv`, you can try this:

```
mydivs = document.getElementsByClassName("Mydiv");

for(var i=0; i<mydivs.length; ++i) {
    subdivs = mydivs[i].getElementsByClassName("Subdiv");

    if (subdivs.length > 0) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // no subdiv found in this Mydiv
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('Mydiv')).forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.innerHTML.match(/class="[^"]*Subdiv"/)) {
        // el is your div
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it doing like so :

```
var targetDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("Mydiv").getElementsByClassName("Subdiv");
```

You will get an array of elements, to get the first sub div with the class `.subdiv`

add the index 0

```
var targetDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("Mydiv").getElementsByClassName("Subdiv")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if in .Mydiv there is .Subdiv

Here's one way to do it:

1. Use querySelectorAll to find every `.Subdiv` that are within `.Mydiv` elements.
2. Loop over them and return their parent, which will be `.Mydiv`.

```js
 var divs = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.Mydiv > .Subdiv'), function (subDiv) {
    return subDiv.parentNode;
});

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Found ' + divs.length + ' .Mydiv that contains .Subdiv'));
```

```html
<div class="Mydiv">
</div>

<div class="Mydiv">
  <div class="Subdiv"></div>
</div>

<div class="Mydiv">
  <div class="Subdiv"></div>
</div>

<div class="Mydiv">
  <div class="Subdiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery:

```
$('.Mydiv').filter(function(i,e) { 
    return $('> .Subdiv', e).size() > 0;
});
```

Finds all "Mydiv" classes and filters if it contains Subdiv class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` and `querySelector`

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".Mydiv"), function(mydiv) {
    if(mydiv.querySelector('.Subdiv')) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

As `querySelectorAll` returns a *HTML Collection* rather than a true array, you can't run `.forEach` directly on it, hence the `[].forEach.call`